# Initial view after gazebo starts

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am not happy with the view on my scene after I start gazebo using rosrun with gazebo and my world file.

How can I set the initial view on my scene for the gazebo simulator.

Thanks and Greetings
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11178/initial-view-after-gazebo-starts/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The world file contains settings for the user camera. Open your world file and search for:

```
  <rendering:gui>
    <type>fltk</type>
    <size>480 320</size>
    <pos>0 0</pos>
    <frames>
      <row height="100%">
        <camera width="100%">
          <xyz>0.3 0 3</xyz>
          <rpy>0 90 90</rpy>
        </camera>
      </row>
    </frames>
  </rendering:gui>
```

As you can see, the `camera` tag contains settings for position and orientation of the camera.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2011-09-13**:
Thank you Lorenz, it worked! I had a wrong syntax, your syntax if working perfect

**Comment by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on 2018-08-20**:
I using Gazebo 9.0 and launching the `empty.world`. It has only 2 models `sun` and `ground_plane`. It does not have any camera settings. How do I configure the camera settings now?

**Comment by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/37094/hbaqueiro/) on 2021-01-05**:
What about switching to orthographic view? Is this possible?

**Comment by [flood](https://answers.ros.org/users/54873/flood/) on 2021-06-21**:
Check out this one @hbaqueiro: https://answers.ros.org/question/380684/setting-orthographic-view-in-gazebo-world-file/?answer=380711#post-id-380711

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Gazebo 9 you do:

```
<world>
  <gui>
    <camera name="user_camera">
      <pose>x y z roll pitch yaw</pose>
    </camera>
  </gui>
</world>
```

Angles are in radians.

---

Originally posted by [artifactz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22331/artifactz/) with karma: 119 on 2020-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

x y z roll pitch yaw
        ortho
        orthographic

This snippet is used to add orthographic view. (Angles are in radians)

---

Originally posted by [ATRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/141083/atrobotics/) with karma: 11 on 2023-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atreya](https://answers.ros.org/users/141259/atreya/) on 2023-03-07**:
It worked for me! Thankyou